# Ubuntu 17.10 (Arty) can't open terminal and sidebar

Tags: 17.10, menu

could you please help me?

Menubar/sidebar disappeared and I cannot launch Terminal. I see some icons on the desktop and I can run programs by clicking on files.

CTRL+ALT+T is not working either.

Thanks

HP notebook model 2SY44ES#ABU 
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz

Comment: What did you do just before it went crazy? Can you post some screenshots pointing out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the terminal by pressing `CTRL+ALT+T` then the system settings by entering `gnome-control-center`.

You can then go in the dock option to display the dock at all time.

Hope it helps

Comment: The shortcut is not working, but thanks anyway. I just amended the question.